# How to use nestjs environment variables in separate class

Tags: node.js, typescript, configuration, environment-variables, nestjs

I use this nestjs guide for configuration https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration. But there shown the usage of environment variables only with using nestjs modules and services but I want to use variables in separate file:
dbConfig.ts that I've now

```
export default {
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || 'db',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'db',
}
```

So I want to use variables like shown in the guide but also I want that dbConfig.ts just export object with config properties

```
export default {
    username: config.get('DB_USERNAME'),
    password: config.get(DB_PASSWORD),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using a configuration service in a separate, non-class file is that all of the config service methods are instance methods, and so they have to come from the instantiated class. What you could do is create a `getDbConfig()` method that returns your database configuration so that the config service class can be injected where it is needed. The other option *could* be to just instantiate another config service class manually, though that seems much hackier and less resource efficient.